How to design the jump in the game like Super Mario?
When I was designing the movement and jumping of the character, I wanted to achieve a jumping effect similar to that in Super Mario, but I had no idea how to achieve this effect. I tried a few times but couldn't get the feel of a normal jump.
Here's some code I have that achieves a similar effect, but the jumps aren't as natural.
const SPEED = 300.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = -300.0
const MAX_JUMP_FORCE = -600.0 
const MAX_JUMP_TIME = 0.5  
var jump_press_duration = 0.0 

func _physics_process(delta):
    print_debug(velocity.y + jump_press_duration * gravity)
    
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity * delta

    ## Handle jump.
    #if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor():
        #velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY
        jump_press_duration = 0  
        
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_accept") and not is_on_floor():
        jump_press_duration += delta
        if jump_press_duration < MAX_JUMP_TIME:
            velocity.y += (MAX_JUMP_FORCE - JUMP_VELOCITY) * (delta / MAX_JUMP_TIME)
    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    # As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
    var direction = Input.get_axis("ui_left", "ui_right")
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)

    move_and_slide()


Take a look at this question:
Godot 4 jumping doesn't work, it seems more like teleporting than jumping
The user uses a tutorial, which handles a pixel perfect jump, which is similar to the original mario games.
